# Cardinality of nonempty sets

Tags: real-analysis

Suppose $X$ and $Y$ are nonempty sets, prove that $\operatorname{card}(X) \leq \operatorname{card}(Y)$ if and only if $\operatorname{card}(Y) \geq \operatorname{card}(X)$

I am not sure how to prove it but I believe need to first say $f:X\rightarrow Y$ is injective, then pick some $x_0\in X$ and define a function $g:Y\rightarrow X$ by $g(y) = f^{-1}(y)$ if $y\in f(X)$, $g(y) = x_0$. This makes $g$ surjective, but I feel like there is something missing or a better way of proving this any suggestions is greatly appreciated.

Comment: The definition of $\operatorname{card}(Y)\ge\operatorname{card}(X)$ that I am aware of is the same as the definition of $\operatorname{card}(X)\le \operatorname{card}(Y)$ that I am aware of.  It means there is some one-to-one function from $X$ into $Y$. I'm guessing you're trying to prove that if there's an injective function $f:X\to Y$ then there is a surjective function $f:Y\to X$. ${}\qquad{}$

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We have two facts to show:

> If there is an injective function $f:X\to Y$, there is a surjective function $g:Y\to X$.

*Proof*: Indeed, take any $x\in X$ and define

$$g(y)=\begin{cases}f^{-1}(y) & \text{if }y\in f(X)\\  x& \text{otherwise} \end{cases}$$

> If there is a surjective function $g:Y\to X$, then there is an injective function $f:X\to Y$.

*Proof:* For every $x\in X$ take any element $y\in g^{-1}(\{x\})$ (Axiom of Choice needed here) and define $f(x)=y$.

I don't know if the Axiom of Choice can be avoided.

Comment: So we need to show those two facts based on the definition of cardinality?

Comment: @ajotatxe in the second part, couldn't we write $g^{-1}(X)$ instead of $g^{-1}(\{x\})$ ?

Comment: Oh, in that case we may not get an injective map